# RadScheduleView, Appointment class - Calculate when is the next appointment

Tags: wpf, telerik, appointment, radscheduleview

I'm using RadScheduleView in a WPF MVVM application. The AppointmentsSource property is bound to an observable collection ObservableCollection in the ViewModel.  So I have all appointments in thew view model.
How can I easily calculate if there is an ongoing appointment at the current moment ? 
How can I calculate when is the next appointment ?

Bear in mind that some of the appointments have the recurrence property set.

Comment: As I see in telerik sources, it's not trivial. In code they iterates through "AppointmentsSource".